# Troubleshooting a MacBook Pro that is not charging from power

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, charging, macos

My MacBook Pro isn't charging, the light on the charger isn't lit, and the battery image indicates it is not charging [image].

The computer is approximately a year old. I've tried multiple outlets, so I know that's not the problem. The connectors look clean, but I cleaned them with a toothpick just to make sure. What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes resetting the SMC works. See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar problem before and the charger wasn't completely broken. Here's what you can try:

1. Plug you MacBook in some other location (seriously, it can be problem with the current in your location)
2. Plug the cable in the opposite way (I mean attach the charger to you MacBook in the way it caps the Ethernet plug).

If it won't help I am afraid you'll have to buy new charger. I would suggest trying another charger before buying a new one to determine if it is your charger or your Mac.

Comment: I don't know if it was putting in the cable the opposite way, or just that I left it alone for a few days, but suddenly it's working again!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like a hardware failure. I've seen a couple others fail. I would recommend taking it to the Genius bar - they may replace the power supply for free (don't bank on it though). I believe they replaced my brother's free.

Are there any other power supplies around that you could test? If not, it will be tested at the Apple store

Answer (score 1):

If your computer is less than a year old, go to a genius bar, they will replace or repair it for free. I also advice you to get a extended warranty as it is kind of a repeating problem. In the past 2.5+ years, i had to replace my charger more than 2 times. But since i had the warranty they just gave me a new one. So it is definitely worth to invest in it. In my case its not only the charger they had to replace several other stuff on several occasions but going to genius bar is the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

A small tip for everyone; if this happens, attach a different charger to the macbook and then your old charger again. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I've literally tried everything, but the only thing you can do to get your Mac charging properly again is to buy a new charger. There are cheaper ones on Amazon that work just as well but make sure they are the same wattage as your current one so it does not cause any problems.

I've gone through this four times and I had the battery replaced once but all in all you just need a new charger.